# Primefaces Organigram - Add table into node

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using the organigram from Primefaces. And I am trying to integrate a html table into a organigram node.
This worked fine. But the table is shown in another place of the page too.

I also tried to use a primefaces table or primefaces panel. But there is the same problem. I get the element in the node AND on another place in the page.

```
<p:organigramNode type="mit" skipLeafHandling="true" >
                        <table>
                            <tr style="background-color: #E6E6E6"> 
                                <td><h:outputText value="Name" /></td>
                                <td><h:outputText value="#{node.name}" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="Functions" /></td>
                                <td><h:outputText value="#node.functions}" /></td> 
                            </tr>
                        </table>
</p:organigramNode>
```

How is it possible to integrate a table into a organigram node?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I couldn't find the root cause (possibly a PF defect). A simple workaround is to use CSS means to remove the duplicate elements from the DOM tree by assigning the property "display: none" to it. Not elegant, but working.

So, you have to give your table an CLASS (or ID) tag and then remove it from the DOM tree via:

```
#organigramPanel_content > .YourTableClassName{
    display:                none                        !important;
}
```

Supposed to work like a charm.